# Find the mean of a column in a data set using pandas and python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I am new to the programming world and have a little problem with my project which I created in the jupyter notebook.
First of all: I installed pandas, tensorflow and numphy and imported a data set.
Then I had the list printed out with the help of pandas (see picture)

[image: the output table].

Now I want to determine the respective mean from the 'Votes' column (from the strings) and then insert this into the column instead of the strings.
I've already tried everything, but unfortunately I can't find the solution.

I hope someone of you can help me :)

Comment: You should probably provide some code so folks can look at what your doing wrong.

Comment: I tried this code:

dataset ['Votes'] = dataset ['Votes']. mean

Comment: Try editing that into the question (Its your first question, so being gentle here. Try editing that line of code into the question). I'm not sure if mean() is the right function as its more about summarizing a row or a column in a datatable,but I *think* apply() might be what your after. Gotta put on your functional programming hat for this one....
https://thispointer.com/pandas-apply-apply-a-function-to-each-row-column-in-dataframe/#:~:text=Python's%20Pandas%20Library%20provides%20an,each%20row%20or%20column%20i.e.&text=Important%20Arguments%20are%3A,series%20and%20returns%20a%20series.

Answer (score 1):

You have a string of a list in each cell. First you need to convert that string to a list. You can use `eval` for it. For reasons explained [here](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) it's better however to use [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval). From this list of numbers you than calculate the mean using `numpy`'s [`mean`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html). All this you [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to the column:

```
import numpy as np
import ast
dataset.Votes = dataset.Votes.apply(lambda x: np.mean(ast.literal_eval(x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Take below `dataframe` for example:

```
In [2210]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[[1,2, 3,2],[2,4,4,2],[3,1,3]], 'B':[1.03, 1.04, 1.05]})

In [2204]: df   
Out[2204]: 
              A    B
0  [1, 2, 3, 2] 1.03
1  [2, 4, 4, 2] 1.04
2     [3, 1, 3] 1.05
```

You can do:

```
In [2213]: import statistics 

In [2211]: df['A'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: statistics.mean(x))

In [2212]: df 
Out[2212]: 
     A    B
0 2.00 1.03
1 3.00 1.04
2 2.33 1.05
```